# Direct3D shared texture created in C++ only displays with one line of pixels in SharpDX (video explanation)

Tags: shared, direct3d, texture2d, sharpdx, direct3d11

When I try to use SharpDX to dump (or display) a shared DirectX10 Texture2D created in C++, the first line of pixels within the texture appears but the rest of the texture is black.

I expect the entire texture to display. The shared format is 32-bit B8G8R8A8_UNORM. I am copying from a source texture which displays correctly within the C++ program, to the shared texture. Both textures are the same size and formats.

In SharpDX if I try any pointer address outside of the texture (even one "pixel" past the end) it will give me a memory access error, so I know i'm using the correct pointer values when moving to the next line of pixels. Pitch is 4 x width (4 bytes per pixel), which is correct from everything I've read. Stride is also 4 x width.

I'm using the latest release version of SharpDX from nuget, 2.6.3.

I've also tried mutex locking using the D3D10_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYEDMUTEX flag, but I got the exact same issue.

Source Texture Creation (c++):

```
ID3D10Texture2D* CreateShared(unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{
    HRESULT err;

    D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC td;
    zero(&td, sizeof(td));
    td.Width = width;
    td.Height = height;
    td.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    td.MipLevels = 1;
    td.ArraySize = 1;
    td.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    td.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_STAGING;
    td.CPUAccessFlags = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    td.MiscFlags = D3D10_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED;

    ID3D10Texture2D *texVal;
    if (FAILED(err = device->CreateTexture2D(&td, NULL, &texVal)))
    {
        AppWarning(TEXT("D3D10Texture::CreateShared: CreateTexture2D failed, result = 0x%08lX"), err);
        return NULL;
    }
    return texVal
}
```

Copying existing (working) texture contents of the same dimensions to the shared texture (c++):

```
device->CopyResource(desttexure, sourcetexture);
device->Flush();
```

Getting the shared handle:

```
texture->GetSharedHandle(&sharedHandle);
```

SharpDX code for opening the shared texture using a known handle:

```
var factory1 = new Factory1();
var adapter1 = factory1.GetAdapter1(0);
var device10 = new Device10(adapter1,SharpDX.Direct3D10.DeviceCreationFlags.Debug);
var ptrVal = ((long)1073743362); // handle of shared texture

var textureD3D10 = device10.OpenSharedResource<SharpDX.Direct3D10.Texture2D>(new IntPtr(ptrVal));
```

SharpDX code for dumping shared texture to disk (C#)

```
public static void Save(this Texture2D texture, Stream stream, SharpDX.Direct3D10.Device device)
{
    var textureCopy = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription
    {
        Width = (int) texture.Description.Width,
        Height = (int) texture.Description.Height,
        MipLevels = 1,
        ArraySize = 1,
        Format = texture.Description.Format,
        Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging,
        SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
        BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
        CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
        OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None
    });
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    device.CopyResource(texture, textureCopy);
    device.Flush();
    Thread.Sleep(50);

    DataStream mipsize;
    var dataBox = textureCopy.Map(
        0,
        MapMode.Read,
        SharpDX.Direct3D10.MapFlags.None,
        out mipsize);


    var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(textureCopy.Description.Width, textureCopy.Description.Height,
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var boundsRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, textureCopy.Description.Width, textureCopy.Description.Height);



    // Copy pixels from screen capture Texture to GDI bitmap
    var mapDest = bitmap.LockBits(boundsRect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    var sourcePtr = dataBox.DataPointer;

    var destPtr = mapDest.Scan0;
    for (int y = 0; y < textureCopy.Description.Height; y++)
    {
        // Copy a single line 
        Utilities.CopyMemory(destPtr, sourcePtr, dataBox.Pitch);

        // Advance pointers
        sourcePtr = IntPtr.Add(sourcePtr, dataBox.Pitch);
        destPtr = IntPtr.Add(destPtr, mapDest.Stride);
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(mapDest);

    var path = "c:\\temp\\screens\\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".bmp";

    // Save the output
    bitmap.Save(path, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    bitmap.Dispose();
}
```

Video explaining issue in depth: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO30oN5kCYY

Can provide more info if required.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Added more detail including relevant code for recreating issue.